# Issue understanding Salesforce Apex Trigger equality check inside in-line SOQL

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex, soql

I ran across this Apex Trigger code that I don't quite understand...

Id is, of course, an Id
hId is a SET

I would normally expect
"WHERE Id IN :hId", instead of
"WHERE Id = :hId"

```apex
trigger linkHusbandAndWife on h2w_c (after insert) {
    
    Set<Id> hId = new Set<Id>();
    for (h2w_c h2w : Trigger.New) {
        hId.add(h2w);
    }
    
    List<Husband_c> husbandlist = [
        SELECT Id Wife_Id 
        FROM Husband_c 
        WHERE Id = :hId
    ];

    ...
}
```

Question: How can "Id = :hId" when hId is a SET?
Is this somehow equivalent to "Id IN :hId" ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the syntax for queries written in Apex is quite forgiving. Especially normal SOQL (written in `[brackets]`, not the dynamic SOQL where you craft query from Strings) . It's more of Apex feature than SOQL, you might have been looking in wrong reference guide. The magic is in "bind variables" (`:`) and you can't always use same trick when making raw query via API for example.

`WHERE Id = :collection` is fine. `Collection` being a single variable of type `Id`, a Set or a List.

`WHERE Id IN :collection` has same result. And you don't even need parentheses!

This means your query can ditch the intermediary step of making a Set, less code to write:

`SELECT Id, Wife_Id__c FROM Husband_c WHERE Id IN :trigger.new`.

A `List<sObject>` will be silently "cast" to `List<Id>` for purposes of SOQL. I used quotes because normally you can't cast it, a sObject will never be an instance of Id. If you'd need similar behaviour in normal code you'd need something like `Set<Id> mySet= new Map<Id, sObject>(mylist).keyset();`.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000090b1IAA

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17695/how-do-i-build-a-soql-query-for-records-in-a-list-of-ids